# What makes the observable I use in this Angular 11 component return undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on adding a *promotions* feature to an Angular 11 e-commerce app.

I have a service that makes a `get` request and reads a JSON containing the campaign's data.

##### The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Campaign } from '../models/campaign';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PromoProductsService {

 public apiURL: string;
 public promo$: Observable<Campaign>;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiURL = `${environment.bffApi}/offer-service`;
    this.promo$ = this.http.get<Campaign>(`${this.apiURL}/campaign`).pipe(shareReplay());
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** the campaign JSON contains other (arrays of) "things" the just banners and I would prefer to make a *single GET request* for all of them. This is why I use `promo$: Observable<Campaign>`.

In the category component I have:

```
public getCampaignBanners() {
    this.promoProductsService.promo$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.campaignData = data;
      this.campaignBanners = this.campaignData.campaign.banners;
     
      if (this.campaignBanners && this.campaignBanners.length > 0) {
        this.displayCampaignBanners();
      } 
    });
}

public displayCampaignBanners(){
    this.productList$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((productList) => {
      this.campaignBanner = this.campaignBanners.find((banner: any) => {
        return banner.category.toLowerCase() == productLists.category_name.toLowerCase();
      });
    });
}
```

##### The problem

Unless I *refresh the page* after accssing a product list, `productList$` is *undefined* and the the line `this.productList$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((productList) => {` throws a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')` error.

###### Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the easiest way to fix this issue?

Comment: I see no code for setting defining or setting the field `productList$`, that would explain the error and that it happens occasionally can be explained by the fact that the containing method that makes the call is conditionally called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Backend with Angular, you need to subscribe to the observable for get data.

I dont really understand why you create an `Observable<Campaign>`

```
    this.http.get<Campaign>(this.apiURL + "/campaign").subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

Or something like this if you want to have a method

```
    public getCampaignBanners() :Observable<Campaign> {
        return this.http.get<Campaign>(this.apiURL + "/campaign");
    }

    // call it after 
    this.promoProductService.getCampaignBanners().subscribe( response => {
        // ...
    })
```

If you want to handle some error you can do this.

```
this.http.get<Campaign>(this.apiURL + "/campaign").subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        switch(error.status){
            case 404:
                // 404 code
                break;
            case 500:
                // 500 code
                break;
            default : 
                break
        }
    })
```

Hope it will help you, maybe it's not the main problem here, did you try to call your API with **POSTMAN** or **CURL** ?
(Sorry for bad english , not native :) )

## EDIT

```
promo: Observable:<any>;

getPromo(){
    if(this.promo == undefined){
        /* Do API CALL and Set promo with Data*/
    }else{
        return this.promo;
    }
}
```

Comment: The campaign JSON contains other (arrays of) "things" the just banners and I would prefer to make a _single GET request_ for all of them. This is why I use `promo$: Observable<Campaign>`.

Comment: No, I don't loose date if refresh the page.

Comment: Maybe the problem come from `shareReplay()` i dont understand really well why is it here:
Take a look : https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay